# React Native i18n set default language on app load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, i18next, react-i18next

I have a simple application, I am using i18next to apply translation in my app.

This is my i18next code:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import en from './en/en.json';
import ar from './ar/ar.json';
import he from './he/he.json';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';




const getDefaultLang = async () => {

  
  const storedLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentLnaguage');
  console.log(storedLang+"aaa");
  /*if(storedLang!= null){
    i18n.defaultLocale = storedLang;
    i18n.locale = storedLang;
    i18n.fallbacks = true;
  }*/

  return i18n
    .use(initReactI18next) 
    .init({
      resources: {
        en: en,
        ar: ar,
        he: he
      },
      //lng: storedLang ? storedLang : 'ar', 
      lng: storedLang || "ar",
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, 
      },

      fallbackLng: ['en', 'ar','he'],
    });
};

export default getDefaultLang();
```

and this is my main app file code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */
/*
 import React from 'react';
 import {Text} from 'react-native';

  //import {SignUpScreen} from './src/components/PlayAround/ResponsiveLayout';
  import {HomeScreen} from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
 
 
  function App (props){
    return(
      <HomeScreen />
    );
  }
  
  
  
  export default App;
  */

import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import  './translations/i18n';
import {View, Text,Pressable} from 'react-native';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {HomeScreen} from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import {LANG_DIR} from './src/const';
import 'intl-pluralrules';



function App(props){


const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();
const [currentLanguage,setLanguage] =useState('ar');


React.useEffect(()=>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem('currentLnaguage').then(val => {
        //changeLanguage(val);
        
    });
},[]);

//console.log(currentLanguage);



const changeLanguage = value => {
    
    AsyncStorage.setItem('currentLnaguage',value);
    i18n
    .changeLanguage(value)
    .then(() => setLanguage(value))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    
};
//AsyncStorage.clear();
return (
    <HomeScreen buttonTitle={t('ordernow')} deliveryText={t('delivery')} />
    

);
};

export default App;
```

My problem is that when I launch the app, there is not default language loaded, when I reload the simulator, the language is loaded.

I tried to use hooks but I didn't succeed.

Any help?

Comment: I also get this problem: react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next

Comment: any solution? or might you have changed it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Arabic as the default language** in your application

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
  (async () => {
    const storedLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentLnaguage');
        const newDefaultLang = storedLang || "ar" // or Change ar with the default language 
        i18n.locale = newDefaultLang 
        changeLanguage(newDefaultLang);
    });
  })()
},[]);
```

If you want to use **the default device language as the default language** in your application

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
  (async () => {
    const storedLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentLnaguage');
        const newDefaultLang = storedLang || i18n.locale
        i18n.locale = newDefaultLang 
        changeLanguage(newDefaultLang)
    });
  })()
},[]);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, where to use this code? because I am getting "unexpected reserver work await"

Comment: I tried to use this but didn't succeed also:
React.useEffect(()=>{
 
 AsyncStorage.getItem('currentLnaguage').then(val => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
  const storedLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentLnaguage');
        const newDefaultLang = storedLang || "ar" // or Change ar with the default language 
        i18n.locale = newDefaultLang 
        changeLanguage(newDefaultLang);
  }
  fetchData();
    });

},[]);

Comment: this bug well fixed with the addition of **async**,
I have now updated the code to use it, 
use this code in app.js when launched app